# How can I apply filename filter in sftp server?

Tags: ssh, centos7, sftp

I want to block all the sftp upload of files that contain some special characters like (':', ';' etc) in the filename. I would like to know that is there any such options available in openssh?

I am currently using openssh 6.6 on CentOS 7.2.

Comment: You can have a look at [MySecureShell](https://mysecureshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags/parents/filespec.html).

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such option available in OpenSSH. Only option I can think of is some automatic script checking the content of the upload directory and moving the files with proper characters to the correct target place. This can be run on logout of the user or periodically using `cron`.